# /dev/null missing, how can I replace it?

Tags: linux, security

How can I replace `/dev/zero` or `/dev/urandom`?

I'd like to zero out the freespace of a headless server that doesn't have either `/dev/zero` or `/dev/urandom` (or `/dev/random`) nor does this machine have access to the internet.

Is it possible to `scp` a special file like `/dev/zero`?

Comment: It makes no sense at all to copy /dev/zero with scp. That is just a node in the file system, there is nothing special or magic about that. It is just like a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special files like devices can be stored in tar files.

It is also possible to use the `mknod` command to create these files given the type, major, and minor numbers of the device file. This information appears in the output of `ls -l`.

For example, on my system:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Nov 25 16:44 /dev/zero
```

Thus, `mknod /dev/zero c 1 5` could be used to recreate `/dev/zero`. (This may not be correct for your system; major and minor numbers are subject to change).

Answer (score 5):

```
mknod /dev/null c 1 3
mknod /dev/zero c 1 5
mknod /dev/random c 1 8
mknod /dev/urandom c 1 9
```

would work on my system.

The numbers (major/minor ID) might be subject to change, however.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your system - this will wipe `/dev`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer].

Comment: @help-info.de this is much simpler than using mknod. so for most users this would be better.